# Wireshark does not pick up outbound traffic

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet, wireshark

I have a bit of 'n problem at a client. We are running a WCF Client/Server application, and for some reason when one of the users try to connect to the server, he gets a timeout, but the second time works.

So I installed Wireshark on his machine to see what happens when the client app tries to connect, however for some reason, I pick up all the incoming traffic from the server but no outbound traffic. On pings everything. So needless to say I cannot see what is sent to the server and if there is a problem there.

I know that the machine has only have one adapter. Can somebody please tell me why Wireshark will only pick up the inbound traffic and not the outbound traffic. If there is any more information needed to give me an answer, please ask.

Regard,
J

Comment: What happens if you try using [WinDump](http://www.winpcap.org/windump/install/default.htm) from the command line?  If it also doesn't capture outbound traffic, it's an issue with  [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org), which both Wireshark and WinDump use.

Comment: I'm going back to the client tomorrow then I can try it. Is there a reason why WinPcap will not picking up the traffic? Network adapter settings etc? The strange thing with the WCF app is that if you didn't connect for over a minute, it doesn't connect, but connects the 2nd time if you do it within the minute "timeout" Its if the network adapter goes to "sleep", but it can't because there is a million other connections :(

Answer (score 2):

In the Network Adapter --> Local Are Connection --> Properties, please uncheck DNE LightWeight Filter option and restart the machine. This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me to resolve this was installing [NPcap](https://wiki.wireshark.org/NPcap).